# How to make my environment variables available for sudo commands?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Currently, I have a script that loads my environment variables. And I'm sourcing it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

# sourcing my env variables
. /etc/profile.d/company_env.sh > /dev/null 2>&1

clear_known_hosts(){
  local known_hosts="${NAGIOS_HOME}/.ssh/known_hosts"
  # clear
  su - nagios -c "echo '' > ${known_hosts}"

}
```

But, removing the sourcing part, because I don't want to add it in every script that may create, my `sudo` command can't find my environment variables, like `NAGIOS_HOME` for example, which is empty.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: `sudo -E` or `sudo --preserve-env` ?

Comment: @anishsane Add that as an answer.

Comment: `known_hosts` isn't an environment variable *at all* here, it's a regular in-process shell variable that isn't exported to the environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[sudo](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/8/sudo/) has option `-E` or long-option `--preserve-env` for this.

```
Usage: sudo -E command args ...
```

Of course, you would need to export the variable from parent shell, in order for it to be visible to `sudo`.

Comment: Yeah, I know that option too. But I was trying to use sudo without it. I'm afraid that is not a good option, is it ? :)